# How can I do a SQL UPDATE in batches, like an Update Top?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is it possible to add a TOP or some sort of paging to a SQL Update statement?

I have an `UPDATE` query, that comes down to something like this:

```
UPDATE XXX SET XXX.YYY = #TempTable.ZZZ
FROM XXX
INNER JOIN (SELECT SomeFields ... ) #TempTable ON XXX.SomeId=#TempTable.SomeId
WHERE SomeConditions
```

This update will affect millions of records, and I need to do it in batches. Like 100.000 at the time (the ordering doesn't matter)

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, I believe you can use TOP in an update statement, like so:

```
UPDATE TOP (10000) XXX SET XXX.YYY = #TempTable.ZZZ
FROM XXX
INNER JOIN (SELECT SomeFields ... ) #TempTable ON XXX.SomeId=#TempTable.SomeId
WHERE SomeConditions
```

Comment: `TOP` as ordered by what? How does the second batch pick up where the first one finished?

Comment: One possibility would be to flag each record as it gets updated, and then add another clause ignoring records that have already been updated. This would require temporarily adding a column to the table (unless there is some efficient way to tell if a record has been updated by virtue of the update itself)

Comment: Eh oke that was simple.. I tested with UPDATE TOP 100000, but that gives an `Incorrect syntax near 100000`, Update TOP (100000) seems to work. @MartinSmith: The 'second batch' doesn't matter in my case. When the first batch is updated, then it won't match the where condition anymore.

Comment: @Martin - the `TOP` operator does not require an `ORDER BY`, so presumably in clustered index order.  As for having the second batch pick up where the first one left off, you would need something in your `WHERE` clause to filter out records that have already been updated.  Hard to say exactly what that would look like though without knowing more info about his query.

Comment: @Erik - Yes, oddly the parentheses are required when using `TOP` in an update (but not in a select..)

Comment: @ErikDekker - And when you get to the end is that not matching join condition detectable without having to scan all million rows?

Comment: @Martin - you can check this easily enough by checking @@rowcount after each update.  If fewer than 10000 rows were updated, you know you are done.

Comment: @EricPetroelje - That isn't what I meant. I meant that when processing later batches if the join needed to process a million rows only to discard most of them as not matching the join filter this will not be efficient.

Comment: @MartinSmith, You are right, but it's for a one-time clean up, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @ErikDekker - Well there may well be a more efficient way as really you would want to avoid rescanning the same rows but you haven't told us your table structures and indexes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`SET ROWCOUNT { number | @number_var }`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx) it limits number of rows processed before stopping the specific query, example below:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10000 -- define maximum updated rows at once

UPDATE XXX SET 
    XXX.YYY = #TempTable.ZZZ
FROM XXX
INNER JOIN (SELECT SomeFields ... ) #TempTable ON XXX.SomeId = #TempTable.SomeId
WHERE XXX.YYY <> #TempTable.ZZZ and OtherConditions

-- don't forget about bellow 
-- after everything is updated
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

I've added `XXX.YYY <> #TempTable.ZZZ` to `where` clause to make sure you will not update twice already updated value.

Setting `ROWCOUNT` to `0` **turn off limits - don't forget about it**.

Comment: Also a good and working answer, but I can accept only one. The other answer is the shortest and fastest way to do what I want.

Comment: SET ROWCOUNT is deprecated for limiting UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE statements. From SQL 2005 onwards, one should rather use TOP.

Comment: above comment is helpful; here is some support for that: https://sqlstudies.com/2013/10/07/use-top-instead-of-set-rowcount/

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like the following

```
declare @i int = 1
while @i <= 10 begin

    UPDATE  top (10) percent
            masterTable set colToUpdate = lt.valCol
    from    masterTable as mt
            inner join lookupTable as lt
                    on mt.colKey = lt.colKey
    where colToUpdate is null

    print @i
    set @i += 1
end

--one final update without TOP (assuming lookupTable.valCol is mostly not null)
UPDATE  --top (10) percent
        masterTable set colToUpdate = lt.valCol
from    masterTable as mt
        inner join lookupTable as lt
                on mt.colKey = lt.colKey            
where colToUpdate is null
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your ability to change the datastructure of the table, I would suggest that you add a field to your table that can hold some sort of batch-identificator. Ie. it can be a date-stamp if you do it daily, an incremenal value or basically any value that you can make unique for your batch. If you take the incremental approach, your update will then be:

```
UPDATE TOP (100000) XXX SET XXX.BATCHID = 1, XXX.YYY = ....
...
WHERE XXX.BATCHID < 1 
  AND (rest of WHERE-clause here).
```

Next time, you'll set the BATCHID = 2 and `WHERE XXX.BATCHID < 2`

If this is to be done repeatedly, you can set an index on the BATCHID and reduce load on the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @updated_Rows INT;
SET @updated_Rows = 1;
WHILE (@updated_Rows > 0)
BEGIN
UPDATE top(10000) XXX SET XXX.YYY = #TempTable.ZZZ FROM XXX
INNER JOIN  #TempTable ON XXX.SomeId=#TempTable.SomeId
WHERE SomeConditions
SET @updated_Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
END
```