# Update via a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a rather large table (150 million rows) that data scrub queries get run on nightly.  Now these queries don't update a lot of records, but to get the records needed, that have to query that single table multiple times in sub queries, which takes some time.

So, would it be better for me to do a normal update statement, or would it be better if I put the few results I needed in a temp table, and then just did an update for those few rows, which would greatly reduce the locks during update.

I'm unsure how an update statement locks work when most of the time is spent querying.  If it is going to only update 5 records, and runs for half and hour, will it release a record that it updated in the first minute, or does it wait till the end of the query?

Thanks

Comment: What about using a cte? You can create your cte and then update the cte which will in turn update the base table.

Comment: I have been rewriting them to use CTEs, and it has helped the performance a lot, but I still have some that have so many subseries and tied to other large tables, that my CTE version takes almost an hour.

Comment: With no details there isn't much I can offer to help performance here. Any locking shouldn't be too bad though because you can use your cte to pair down to only the rows you need to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use (and look into) into the [`ROWLOCK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) table hint. You can use it with the update statement while updating in batches of 5000 rows of less. This will attempt to place row locks in the target table (or on index keys, if a covering index is present). If for some reason that fails, the lock will be escalated to a table lock.

[From MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx) (as for reasons why lock escalation might occur):

> When the Database Engine checks for possible escalations at every 1250
>   newly acquired locks, a lock escalation will occur if and only if a
>   Transact-SQL statement has acquired at least 5000 locks on a single
>   reference of a table. Lock escalation is triggered when a Transact-SQL
>   statement acquires at least 5,000 locks on a single reference of a
>   table. For example, lock escalation is not triggered if a statement
>   acquires 3,000 locks in one index and 3,000 locks in another index of
>   the same table. Similarly, lock escalation is not triggered if a
>   statement has a self join on a table, and each reference to the table
>   only acquires 3,000 locks in the table.

Actually, there's more to read in this last article. You should have a look at mixed lock type escalation section.

Comment: So does a long updating query wait till the query is done to release all of the locks? Or, as each records is updated, is it released?

Comment: @Limey: No, locks are released once the update statement is completed (so, when the query is done).

Comment: Then for a small amount of updates, it would be best to find the records, put them in a temp table, and then use that to run the update?

Comment: @Limey: Yes, that would be best. Make sure to run the update in batches (up to 5k). You can do the batching with something [similar to this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8820594/1119545).