# Display a Message for Every 10000 records on console application and SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, console-application

I am dealing with a Console application in which it is getting 1million of records form one table which is in different server and storing in to a data table and sending the DataTable to SQL and inserting/updating in to our table using a merge statement. To get the data it is taking 25min and for inserting it takes 20min, i am using SQL-Server management studio-2012.

I would like to give information on the front screen by displaying "10000 records are inserted/updated" for every 10000 records or by a specific time delay of 10sec.

Is there a way to achieve this using the SQL(for every 10000 records updated, need to send a message to App) or by Console Application. Below is my Stored procedure using for it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Data_Inserting_In_To_QueueTable]

    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Values AS [dbo].[Type_Table] READONLY  

AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ;WITH CTE_data_codes AS(
        select [NO], [ID], [Name], [Code]  from @SearchValues where [No] != '0'
        )

    MERGE tbl__QueueTable_Codes AS t
        -- Values is the temp table in which data is coming from the console application
        USING CTE_data_codes  AS s
        ON (s.Code = t.Code and s.NO = t.NO and s.ID = t.ID)


        WHEN NOT MATCHED by target
            --Newly added values in Values has been updated in tbl__QueueTable_Codes
            THEN INSERT(NO, Name, ID, Code, Deleted)
            VALUES(s.[NO], s.[Name], s.[ID], s.[Code], 0)

         WHEN NOT MATCHED by source
            --It means the value has been deleted in Value, hence we put a flag for deleted ones as '1'.
            THEN  UPDATE            
            SET t.Deleted = 1;

END
```

Comment: I think you can use `SqlNotificationRequest`, but I don't know much about it.

Comment: You'd have to first change your stored procedure to do the work in batches (probably of 10,000 rows).

Comment: @mallan1121 could you please provide any example for that.Thanks.

Comment: @Virat Answer to this question will get you started. You will need some way of identifying which rows have already been updated / inserted so you don't get stuck processing the same ones over and over. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820553/how-can-i-do-a-sql-update-in-batches-like-an-update-top

Comment: Can you give us the c# code that you're using for the insert as well, as there might be ways to improve upon what you're doing on the code side as well.

Comment: Strongly recommend using `bulkcopy`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the insert/merge be sequential you should add parallelism to your insert.

In my case I process `AVL` gps data around `4000 records/min` each record need to find the `near_road` to know where the car is. The function to find the road is linear time `10ms` so for `4000` records is `40 sec`.

So instead of sending one `INSERT` query for 4000 records, I use `C#` to send `4x1000` and take ~10 seconds instead.

In this [**QUESTION**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155253/splitting-a-list-of-numbers-into-multiple-lists/155255#155255) you can see how I split the avl into ranges and send to a stored procedure and one of the answer is a suggestion to use `Parallel.ForEach` in C#

Comment: @Virat. You didnt make any comment on this one,. But using `Parallel.ForEach` you can set a `console.Write` in the body section to keep track of progress.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible. I'm not sure what are you using to actually get the data from the database but the [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) class is effectively a forward-only stream that processes the query output row-by-row. You could monitor the count and call a delegate (Action) that prints your progress every time you get another *N* rows by wrapping your method within a class that accepts the delegate as a parameter.

Here is an example (*pseudocode, never actually checked it*) as I see it:

```
public class ReadWriteWithProgress {

    public List<ClassWeAreReading> ReadData(Action<int> rowCountReporter) {
        List<ClassWeAreReading> result = new List<ClassWeAreReading>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var queryToExecute = "SELECT Id, Name FROM dbo.Table";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryToExecute, connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dataReader != null) {
                        int rowCounter = 0;
                        while (dataReader.Read()) {
                             var intermediateResult = new ClassWeAreReading();
                             intermediateResult.Id = (int) dataReader["Id"];
                             intermediateResult.Name = dataReader["Name"].ToString();
                             rowCounter++;
                             if (rowCounter % 1000 == 0) {
                                 if (rowCountReporter != null) {
                                     rowCountReporter (rowCounter);
                                 }
                             }
                             result.Add(intermediateResult);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void LoadData(List<ClassWeAreReading> dataToLoad, Action<int> rowCountReporter) {
         int rowCounter = 0;
         // Iterate through the list (it might be IEnumerable or any other kind of collection you can iterate through) and use the callback in the same manner as above
        // ...
           rowCounter++;
               if (rowCounter % 1000 == 0) {
                   if (rowCountReporter != null) {
                       rowCountReporter (rowCounter);
                   }
               }
        // ...
    }
}

// Then you need this kind of method to use as a callback:

private static void PrintRowCount(int rowCount){
    Console.WriteLine("{0} rows transferred...", rowCount);
}

private static void PrintUpdateRowCount(int rowCount){
    Console.WriteLine("{0} rows written...", rowCount);
}

// And finally you can start your stuff and pass in the method:

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var readerWithProgress = new ReadWriteWithProgress();
    var result = readerWithProgress.ReadData(PrintRowCount);
    readerWithProgress.LoadData(result, PrintUpdateRowCount);
}
```

Comment: The question is about modifying and/or creating data using a merge operation. As far as I know, the SqlDataReader is only supported when _reading_ data. It would also be a bad idea to be able to intercept such a merge process, just by pausing you're data reader or even if you throw an exception somewhere along the lines, because what should the sql-server do then? Keep it locked or commit the current state? Even if you would use an update statement with an output method in sql, you would eventually always get the data after the operation is completed, not while it is executing.

Comment: @Silvermind I might have misunderstood the question but the author is saying that the data is first read (loaded into a data table, in-memory), then inserted/updated. If that's the case the suggested solution can be used to load the data and then the `result` list can be iterated through in the same manner  with the same callback for progress reporting... Unless I really misunderstand what's going on.

Comment: @Silvermind I've updated the answer. As far as I understand the question it's about reporting the progress and not improving the performance of the data read/load. If it's not the case the author could let us know :)

Comment: @Phil P, i read your comments, your right, i am loading the data in to data table first and then sending the datatable to sql.where after it is taking 20min of time to update the data.Will try your solution and let you know.